# Trying to run sc create from PowerShell with nested quotes and can't get it to work

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to programmatically create a service where the binpath contains nested quotes for a parameter that contains spaces.

Running it via command prompt works fine but it fails in powershell using Invoke-Expression. I've tried playing around with here strings and scriptblocks but still can't get it to work.

```
$serviceName = "my service"
$svcBinaryPath = '\"' + $pathToExe + '\" \"' + $parameterWithSpaces + '\"'

$cmd = "sc.exe create $('"' + $serviceName + '"') binpath= $('"' + $svcBinaryPath + '"')"
Invoke-Command $cmd
```

Printing out `$cmd` and running what it shows in command prompt works fine.

Comment: You don't need `Invoke-Command` here at all. `sc.exe create "$serviceName" binpath= "$svcBinaryPath"` should do fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just pass a string to `Invoke-Command` and you don't need it, just run it in this way:

```
$serviceName = "my service"
$scvBinaryPath = '\"' + $pathToExe + '\" \"' + $parameterWithSpaces + '\"'
sc.exe create $serviceName binpath= $svbBinaryPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a new-service cmdlet for creating services.

```
PS C:\users\j> get-command -noun service

CommandType     Name                      Version    Source
-----------     ----                      -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-Service               3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          New-Service               3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Restart-Service           3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Resume-Service            3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Set-Service               3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Start-Service             3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Stop-Service              3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet          Suspend-Service           3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

Example to create the new service with quotes around:

```
New-Service -Name $serviceName -BinaryPathName "`"$pathToExe $parameterWithSpaces`""
```